# Custom building jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery for a mobile app, but I don't use all or even half of its modules so I'm looking to nix those and reduce the size a bit. (No, I don't want to use Zepto or other libraries for some reasons).

There was one: projects.jga.me/jquery-builder/ but its not maintained anymore.

jQuery Uncompressed: http://pastebin.com/CwUT9U8p

Wondering which functions/modules I can safely remove, any pointers would help.

Comment: How should we know which functions you can remove, it depends on which functions you use.

Comment: I just use getJSON and the sizzle engine. No animation, nothing else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `grunt` to build the jquery modules you want to use into a custom version of jquery, it's documented on the [jquery git repo here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery#modules)

It's worth noting though that jquery uses a lot of internal code calls, so even a trimmed down version wont be as small as you might like (possibliy not even as small as a minified gzip version of the full lib)

If you are only wanting sizzle and getJson have you though of using the stand [alone sizzle lib](http://sizzlejs.com/) and a lightweight json ajax wrapper? there are [microlibs for ajax/json here](http://microjs.com/#json)

Comment: Wasn't aware of that. Nice.